# Calculating $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta))$

Tags: galois-theory

I am considering the Galois extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$, where $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta)$, and $\zeta$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

I've found that $Aut(L/\mathbb{Q})$ can be viewed as being the same as $S_3$.  Also, I've noted that $L$ is the splitting field of $x^3 -2$, and have now ordered the roots as $\alpha_1 = \sqrt[3]{2}$, $\alpha_2 = \zeta \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\alpha_3 = \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{2}$.

I want to calculate $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^*$; i.e.:  $Aut(L/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta))$ as a subgroup of $S_3$.

I know can write $\zeta = \frac{\alpha_3}{\alpha_2} = \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}$.  I want to find all $\sigma \in S_3$ s.t. $\sigma(\zeta) = \zeta$.

Of course, the identity will be one such $\sigma$.  My first thoughts for others would be take the permutation $(1, 3, 2)$, as this means $\sigma(\frac{\alpha_3}{\alpha_2}) = \sigma(\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1})$.  However, this leaves us with something not nice for $\sigma(\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1})$, so I'm thinking that's wrong.

I don't think any permutations swapping two elements will work, ruling out $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$ and $(2,3)$, and $(1, 2, 3)$ has similar problems to above.

So, am I right in saying $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^* = \{1\}$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not right. Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory says that your group *must* have the same order as the field extension degree $[L\colon\mathbb Q(\zeta)]$. How about sending the root $\root3\of2$ to the number $\zeta\root3\of2$, which is also a root. Where the other roots go is forced on you then.